# Upload Multiple Files and Download its Zip

Tags: php, mongodb, file-upload

I have been working on `CRUD` operation with `MongoDB` and `PHP`. I am able to develop a demo application for the same along with file upload feature where user can upload an `image`, `view` and `delete` it.

**[EDIT]**

**File Upload**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
        $conn = new MongoClient();
        $db = $conn->selectDB('mydb');
        $gridfs = $db->getGridFS();

        $id = $gridfs->storeUpload('pic', array('tag' => ""));
        $gridfsFile = $gridfs->get($id);
        var_dump($gridfsFile->file);
        /*
         $files = $db->fs->files;
        $files->update(array("filename" => $_FILES['pic']['name']), array('$set' => array("enterby" => "Gayatri patel", "tag" =>"image")));*/
        $conn->close();
}
?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="username">Select Type</label>
    <select name="document_type" id="document_type">
        <option value="image/jpeg">jpg</option>
        <option value="image/gif">gif</option>
        <option value="image/png">png</option>
        <option value="text/plain">txt</option>
        <option value="application/pdf">pdf</option>
        <option value="application/x-zip">zip</option>
    </select>

    <label for="pic">Please upload a profile picture:</label>
    <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" />

    <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" />
</form>
```

**File List**

```
<?php
   $conn = new MongoClient();
    $db = $conn->selectDB('mydb');        // Authenticate to MongoDB
    $grid = $db->getGridFS();                    // Initialize GridFS

    $cursor = $grid->find();

    foreach ($cursor as $obj) {                   // iterate through the results
        echo 'Filename: <a href="fileDownload.php?file='.urlencode ($obj->getFilename()).'">'.$obj->getFilename().'</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Size: '.$obj->getSize().'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="fileDelete.php?file='.urlencode ($obj->getFilename()).'">Delete</a><br/>';
    }

    $conn->close();                                // Disconnect from Server
    exit(0);
?>
```

**File View**

```
<?php
    $conn = new MongoClient();
    $db = $conn->selectDB('mydb');        // Authenticate to MongoDB
    $grid = $db->getGridFS();                   // Initialize GridFS

   $ask = urldecode($_REQUEST['file']);                   // Get filename requested


    $file = $grid->findOne(array('filename' => $ask));
    $files = $db->fs->files;
    $file1 = $files->findOne(array('filename' => $ask));
    $id = $file->file['_id'];

    if ( (substr($ask,-3) == 'zip') || (substr($ask,-3) == 'pdf') ) {
       /* Any file types you want to be downloaded can be listed in this */
       header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.'"'.$ask.'"');
       header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
       $cursor = $db->fs->chunks->find(array("files_id" => $id))->sort(array("n" => 1));
       foreach($cursor as $chunk) {
          echo $chunk['data']->bin;
       }
    }
    else {
       //header('Content-Type: '.$file1["contentType"]);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
       echo $file->getBytes();
    }   

    $conn->close();                                // Disconnect from Server
    exit(0);
?>
```

**File Delete**

```
<?php
   $conn = new MongoClient();
    $db = $conn->selectDB('mydb');        // Authenticate to MongoDB
    $grid = $db->getGridFS();                    // Initialize GridFS

    $filename = urldecode($_REQUEST["file"]);                // Get requested filename

    $file = $grid->findOne($filename);             // Find file in GridFS
    $id = $file->file['_id'];                    // Get the files ID
    $grid->delete($id);                            // Delete the file

    $conn->close();                                // Disconnect from Server
    exit(0);
?>
```

Now I need to develop multiple file uploads using `MongoDB`. The uses cases are as below

1. If user uploads single image, give the option to `view` it
2. If user uploads more than one image i.e. multiple file upload, give
   the option to `download` it in `.zip` format.

How can I achieve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you dont need to use `<select name="document_type" id="document_type">` to determine the file mime type. the file $_FILES[fieldname] should return the mime type for the file ($_FILES['pics']['type']).
2. I assume you have multiple upload fields? on your form name all the file inputs as  pics[]. the "[]" will make the uploaded files an array back in the php script. you can retrieve them by running a for loop on $_FILES['pics'];
3. files can be zipped with php using an extra extension see the manual first. http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php
4. on the line where you echo the pdf content after the header there might be a headers already sent error.

`
  //form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="username">Select Type</label>
<label for="pic">Please upload a profile picture:</label>
<input type="file" name="pics[]"/>
<input type="file" name="pics[]"/>
<input type="file" name="pics[]"/>
<input type="file" name="pics[]"/>

<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" />
</form>
```

``

```
    if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']) && isset($_FILES['pics'])){
        $conn = new MongoClient();
        $db = $conn->selectDB('mydb');
        $gridfs = $db->getGridFS('uploads');
        $uploadedIds = array();
        $acceptedTypes = array('image/jpeg', 'application/pdf');

        foreach ($_FILES['pics'] as $file) {
            if(in_array($file['type'], $acceptedTypes)){
                $id = $gridfs->storeFile($file['tmp_name'], array('tag' => "",'filename' => 'filename', 'type' => $file['type']));
                array_push($uploadedIds, (string)$id);
            }else{
                echo 'file is not of correct type';
            }
        }

        print_r($uploadedIds);
        $conn->close();
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    //view file
    // you need to feth files from /?files[]=file1.jpg&files[]=file1.jpg

        $conn = new MongoClient();
        $db = $conn->selectDB('mydb'); 
        $grid = $db->getGridFS('uploads');  

        $ask = $_GET['files']; 

        if(count($ask) == 1){
            $file = $grid->findOne(array('filename' => $ask[0]));
            header('Content-Type: '.$file['type']);
            echo $file->getBytes();
            exit();
        }else{
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

            foreach ($ask as $f) {
                $file = $grid->findOne(array('filename' => $f));
                echo $file->getBytes();
            }
            exit();
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but how can I get along with the code to upload multiple files ? Do we have a working demo ?

Comment: multiple as in php or your form ?

Comment: Multiple image upload or drag and drop.

Comment: can you revise my code to make it work with multiple file uploads ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy i did not test the code. I think this is how it should be done.

Comment: There is an exception saying `Undefined index: type`

Comment: I can not download the files in zip format. It says zip file is invalid.

Comment: are you using a php extension to zip or just setting headers ?

Comment: as i said. you need to zip the files using a php extension. then echo it with proper headers.